# Why isn't the OpenACC tutorial code executing on the GPU?

Tags: g++, openacc

I'm trying to run the OpenACC tutorial at https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/OpenACC#OpenACC_kernels_Construct_Optimization_Tutorial

The compiler is g++ 9.2 64-bit as part of the MSYS MINGW64 package.

C:\Users\TJ\Documents\GpuDemo>where g++

C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe

C:\Users\TJ\Documents\GpuDemo>g++ --version

g++ (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Here's the command that builds my code:

g++ -m64 -std=c++17 gpudemo.cpp -o gpudemo.exe -fopenmp -fopenacc

The single-thread and OpenMP multi-thread calls work fine.  But the OpenACC code is not going to the GPU; it's running on the CPU.  The GPU run time is the same as the single-thread run time.  My computer is a Lenovo D20 with dual Intel Xeon 5675 processors (6 cores each) and an NVidia GeForce GTX 970 video card, running Windows 7 Pro SP1 64-bit.

Program output:

C:\Users\TJ\Documents\GpuDemo>gpudemo

Multiply a 2000x2000 matrix.

single thread: 54104.1 milliseconds

multi thread:   5036.29 milliseconds

GPU:           54371.1 milliseconds

If I set the environment variable ACC_DEVICE_TYPE=NVIDIA, it gives an error "libgomp: device type NVIDIA not supported."

How can I get this tutorial code to use the GPU?

```
// https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/OpenACC


#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

#define N 2000

void matrix_multiply_single_thread (float r[N][N], const float a[N][N], const float b[N][N])
{
  for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
          float sum = 0;
          for (int k = 0; k < N ; k++)
            sum += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
          r[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
}

void matrix_multiply_multi_thread (float r[N][N], const float a[N][N], const float b[N][N])
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
          float sum = 0;
          for (int k = 0; k < N ; k++)
            sum += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
          r[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
}

void matrix_multiply_gpu (float r[N][N], const float a[N][N], const float b[N][N])
{
  #pragma acc kernels \
    copy(r[0:N][0:N], a[0:N][0:N], b[0:N][0:N])
  {
    #pragma acc loop independent
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
      {
        #pragma acc loop independent
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
          {
            float sum = 0;
            // #pragma acc loop seq
            #pragma acc loop independent reduction(+: sum)
            for (int k = 0; k < N ; k++)
              sum += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            r[i][j] = sum;
          }
      }
  }
}

static float a[N][N], b[N][N], r[N][N];

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Multiply a " << N << "x" << N << " matrix.\n\n";
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = rand();
            b[i][j] = rand();
        }
    }
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    matrix_multiply_single_thread(r, a, b);
    auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(finish - start);
    double milliseconds = (double)microseconds.count() / 1000;
    std::cout << "\nsingle thread: " << milliseconds << " milliseconds\n";

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    matrix_multiply_multi_thread(r, a, b);
    finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(finish - start);
    milliseconds = (double)microseconds.count() / 1000;
    std::cout << "multi thread:   " << milliseconds << " milliseconds\n";

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    matrix_multiply_gpu(r, a, b);
    finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(finish - start);
    milliseconds = (double)microseconds.count() / 1000;
    std::cout << "GPU:           " << milliseconds << " milliseconds\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in this.  I'm part of the team who contributed OpenACC support and GPU code offloading to GCC, and we're still working on that.

The compiler you're using has not been built with support for GPU code offloading -- as indicated by the error message "libgomp: device type NVIDIA not supported" that you ran into.

---

Indeed, we so far haven't seen any reports of people building GCC with code offloading support for Windows hosts.  It's likely that a bit of development effort for GCC/nvptx-tools will be required, but neither have we so far been contracted to work on that, nor has any volunteer contributed the respective code changes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I had read somewhere that GCC 9.x supported OpenACC, but apparently missed the part that it was Linux only.